# ElasticSearch: get new records

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a script that runs periodically, and on each run I want it to get the records that were added to the DB since the last run. How can I achieve this?

I prefer not to change anything in the way records are added to the DB if I don't have to.

Comment: Is there any kind of sequence (ids, timestamps, etc) in your data?  Elasticsearch doesn't create one for you, so you'll need to do that if you're not already.

Comment: There are timestamps. The order in which records are entered should be in the same order as the timestamps, but I can't guarantee that in case records are added at a high rate. I think the ids are auto-generated (though I need to make sure), if they are - do they follow the order in which records were added?

Comment: The Elasticsearch generated ids are unique but not necessarily ordered.  If the timestamps aren't good enough, you'll need to add some other sort of sequence field as you're inserting.

Comment: True. If you want to turn that into an answer I'll accept it.